# Accessing UNIX environment variables from ORACLE reports

Tags: oracle, unix, oraclereports

How do I use a environment variable set in UNIX in Oracle Reports?
I am using Reports 11.1.2

Comment: How do you want to "use" the variables?  The output directory is controlled elsewhere, for example.

Comment: I want to print the environment variable in a Field in Oracle reports.